# Using SetTimeOut inside for loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop, asynchronous, callback, event-loop

#### I have recently come up with a question asking to find outputs of these 2 code snippets:

First one:

```js
let i;

for (i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(i);
  }, 0);
}
```

Second one:

```js
for (let i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(i);
  }, 0);
}
```

I am familiar with how **Event Loop** works. in Each iteration callback function inside *setTimeout* is getting added to the task queue after waiting for 0 millisecond. As soon as **Call stack** is empty those callback functions are fired.

But Both Code Snippets are giving different results.

Help me to get an explanation on why they are giving different results.

Comment: Put simply, in the second snippet each for loop iteration has its own `i`.

Comment: In the first code snippet, each callback function of `setTimeout` forms a closure over the _same_ variable `i`, whereas in the second code snippet, each iteration of the loop has a _different_ `i` variable, this means that each time `setTimeout` is called, its callback function forms a closure over a _different_ `i` variable, which was created just for that iteration of the loop. if you are interested in understanding this problem of closures in loops, here's an [article](https://blog.yousafkhan.me/understanding-closures-in-loops-problem-and-how-it-is-solved-in-es6) about this problem.

Comment: Thank you @Yousaf for your explanation and your article is great.